# fail to stream file using handler and with 206 Partial Response

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, video

I'm trying to write a Generic Handler (**Stream.ashx**) in ASP.NET C# (v4.5) to support 206 Partial Content responses, to give a better User Experience when streaming videos, e.g. adding support for seeking. the page is used like this `/Stream.ashx?relative%5cto%5cvideo.mp4`.

I have written the code below, but the browser's HTML5 video player fails to load the video, right clicking the video placeholder and saving the video, results in an exact download of the video (SHA1 hashes match).

To try to understand what is wrong I have run **WireShark** against a request and response, as far as I can tell everything seems to be working. the initial (200) response has the accept-ranges: bytes header, then the second (206) response has the `Accept-Ranges:bytes`, `Cache-Control:private`, `Content-Length:183618615`, `Content-Range:0-183618614/183618615` & `Content-Type:video/mp4` headers.

I've been trying to get this working for a few days, but cannot work it out, I'm sure I'll kick myself when someone points out why it is not working...

What I have so far:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        HttpRequest request = context.Request;
        HttpResponse response = context.Response;
        response.ClearHeaders();
        response.ClearContent();

        // request sanity checks (e.g. is rootPath accessible, is there a QueryString etc.)
        string requestedFilePath = rootPath + request.QueryString[0];
        if (!File.Exists(requestedFilePath))
        {
            response.StatusCode = 404;
            response.Flush();
            response.End();
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            FileStream test = File.OpenRead(requestedFilePath);
            test.Close();
            test.Dispose();
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            response.StatusCode = 403;
            response.Flush();
            response.End();
            return;
        }
        response.Headers.Add("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
        FileInfo aboutFile = new FileInfo(requestedFilePath);
        int length = (int)aboutFile.Length;
        int fullLength = length;
        int startAt = 0;
        int endAt = length - 1;

        if (request.Headers["Range"] != null)
        {
            response.StatusCode = 206;
            response.StatusDescription = "Partial Content";

            string rangeString = request.Headers["Range"];
            rangeString = rangeString.Substring(6);
            string[] rangeParts = rangeString.Split('-');
            startAt = Convert.ToInt32(rangeParts[0]);
            if (rangeString.EndsWith("-"))
            {
                length = fullLength - startAt;
            }
            else
            {
                endAt = Convert.ToInt32(rangeParts[1]);
                length = (endAt - startAt) + 1;
            }
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Range", startAt + "-" + endAt + "/" + fullLength);
        }

        response.Headers.Add("Content-Length", length.ToString());
        response.ContentType = Multimedia.DetectMIMEType(requestedFilePath);
        FileStream fileReader = new FileStream(requestedFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        CreatePartialContent(fileReader, response.OutputStream, startAt, endAt);
        fileReader.Close();
        fileReader.Dispose();
        response.OutputStream.Close();
        try
        {
            response.Flush();
        }
        catch (HttpException) { }
        try
        {
            response.Close();
        }
        catch (HttpException) { }
    }

    private static void CreatePartialContent(FileStream inputStream, System.IO.Stream outputStream, long start, long end)
    {
        int count = 0;
        // 50MiB buffer
        int bufferSize = 52428800;
        long remainingBytes = end - start + 1;
        long position = start;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        inputStream.Position = position;
        while (position <= end)
        {
            try
            {
                if (remainingBytes > bufferSize)
                {
                    count = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }
                else
                {
                    count = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)remainingBytes);
                }
                outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                break;
            }
            position = inputStream.Position;
            remainingBytes = (end - position) + 1;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any tips!!

Comment: try with this option `context.Response.Buffer = false;` to disable the buffer and direct send your data

Comment: Thanks @Aristos , I've added `response.Buffer = false;` after `response.ClearContent();` however I'm getting the same results as before.